# RelativeSource constructor optional argument

Tags: c#, xaml, constructor

In looking through the MS Reference source they show the constructors for RelativeSource. Below is the one used when you specify FindAncestor as the mode.

```
public RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode mode, Type ancestorType, int ancestorLevel)
        {
            InitializeMode(mode);
            AncestorType = ancestorType;
            AncestorLevel = ancestorLevel;
        }
```

Now I don't see anything that allows optional arguments here.

And yet the below XAML works fine even though I haven't specified AncestorLevel.

```
    <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Height}"/>
```

Why can I leave the AncestorLevel argument out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Height}" is not calling the constructor for RelativeSource.  It is calling the [Binding XAML Markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [RelativeSource XAML Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  These extensions have their own syntax and provide their own defaults.

Answer (score 1):

In XAML include Markup Extensions all objects are instantiated per parameterless default constructor. All properties are set after creation. The constructor with parameters is not meant for XAML

Answer (score 0):

Check the XAML [RelativeSource MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599(v=vs.110).aspx):

**intLevel** - Optional for FindAncestor mode. An ancestor level (evaluated towards the parent direction in the logical tree).